# Renderscript errors in LogCat

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I'm noticing some errors in LogCat relating to a RenderScript script I am running.

The script seems to work OK, but I'm curious as to what these errors might mean.

```
E/Adreno-RS﹕ <rsdQueryGlobals:1173>: ERROR: Invalid attribute 20 specified for global: inputFrame
W/Adreno-RS﹕ <rsdVendorScriptInitQCOM:842>: ERROR: rsdQueryGlobals returned -30
```

Thanks!

Comment: At desktop, my Android SDK gives many memory leaks and exceptions on top of warnings but runs fine on my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are harmless logspam from Qualcomm's Adreno driver. You can ignore them.